# Convert data type varchar to data type date in MySQL (one Table)

Tags: mysql, date, varchar

I have data on `TGLBAYAR` column in "pelayanan" table. I want to convert them to type data DATE on new column `BAYAR`.

I already have column `BAYAR` with data type DATE which the value is NULL.

How can I solve this problem  in MySQL?

The data on `TGLBAYAR` is 31/07/2014 -> dd/mm/yy

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, pelayanan.TGLBAYAR , 103)
```

Comment: It has error. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`pelayanan2`.TGLBAYAR , 103)' at line 1

Comment: The data on cloumn TGLBAYAR is 07122014 I want to convert this into date in colum BAYAR

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
SELECT convert(datetime, pelayanan.TGLBAYAR , 101)
```

Or

```
SELECT CAST(TGLBAYAR AS DATETIME) AS TGLBAYAR FROM pelayanan
```

Comment: It same. It has error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`TGLBAYAR` , 112)' at line 1

Comment: Try to use this. set your column name and table name in here SELECT CONVERT(DATE, colName, 112) AS convertedDate FROM tableA;  -- Replace column name and table name

Comment: SELECT CAST(TGLBAYAR AS DATETIME) AS TGLBAYAR FROM pelayanan

Answer (score 0):

You can convert using **str_date(str,format)**

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('04/31/2004', '%m/%d/%Y');
```

OUTPUT

```
'2004-04-31'
```

for more details use [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)